# Mail sending error in VBA form

Tags: windows, smtp, outlook, email, microsoft-office

: I am getting the following error

```
The host 'smtp' could not be found. Please verify that you have entered the server name correctly. Account: 'pop3', Server: 'smtp', Protocol: SMTP, Port: 25, Secure(SSL): No, Socket Error: 11001, Error Number: 0x800CCC0D
```

while clicking a button to send some contents as mail using VBA form. I know that this error is related to the configuration problem of the mail client. But,the outlook installed in my machine can send and recieve mails without any errors.

I copied the mdb vba application to another computer, but while sending by clicking button,its not giving the error while i send using the same button in my computer.

I have also checked the profile in the control panel> mail in my computer and seen that default profile for outlook is selected.

There are two mail accounts configured in the one profile of my outlook. is this causing the issue?

Comment: What is the SMTP server hostname configured as in the account setup in Outlook?

Comment: its configured properly...i could send and recieve mails in outlook mail client

Comment: Not what I asked, what's it configured as? Is it set to "smtp"? That is generally not going to be a valid hostname unless your /etc/hosts has it setup, or it is setup in your DNS server. If it's not "smtp" in your Outlook account then the VBA form is not working properly.

Comment: How to check this?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a name resolution issue.

You have your SMTP server set in your script as: Server: 'smtp' is smtp really the name of your mail server? Is this the name that is in Outlook as your Outgoing (SMTP) server?

If it is then can you ping this server from your machine, is the name resolving correctly. If not then you have a DNS problem you need to fix.